# Port forwarding : open port without any response

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, port

I've been playing around with my router recently to be able to access my localhost (ran by xampp) from outside. I've managed to open ports 80 and 443 and I've confirmed it with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ . I've also turned off the windows firewall. But when I try my external ip address, it says there was no response. What should I do ?

Comment: Of cause you can open ports on you router but behind your router you could have more than one device. So you need to map the port to a specifc computer behind your router e.g 192.168.1.100 .. What router do you use anyways?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I'm using a Netgear one. My PC is connected via cable, and I've given it a static ip, and as far as I know, I've mapped these ports to my PC's ip ( 10.1.1.2 )

Comment: First step are you able to access the website from another device in your local network?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I just checked with my phone and I could access it.

Comment: Ok, good sign. So you computer listens to the port 80. So the problem must be how the router handels requests on port 80. You could try to put your computer into the DMZ. If it works there there is something wrong with the port forwarding. Also consider that the this hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147430/how-do-i-make-my-xampp-server-public-using-my-public-ip-address

Comment: @IvanViktorovic how do I put it into DMZ ? any good article/link for a non-pro ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29

Comment: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1118

Comment: Be aware this should only be for test purpose. DO NOT leave you computer configured as the DMZ host, there are several security issues with that.

Comment: Many routers don't work well forwarding the default http/https ports. Try changing your routers management ports if possible, then test the port forwarding.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic It still didnt work in DMZ :/

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie I tried other ports, but they dont "open" according to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: @hakim-sina So here's what I'm trying to get at. Your router is managed over port 80 and port 443. Those are HTTP and HTTPS respectively. If you can, change those ports in the router management settings. This does not have to do with port forwarding. If you can't, you most likely cannot forward those ports through the router you have.

Comment: You could try to change the port your website/PC listen to. http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/